# How can I allow URL's starting with www in input without using javascript?

Tags: html, regex, input

I want to use the html attribut [required pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url) instead of javascript to allow URLs that start with `www`. So both examples should be valid:

- `www.some.site.com`
- `http://some.site.com`

I've tried `required pattern="https?:\/\/.+|www.+"` but it's not working (see my [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpd8enzr/2/)).

The way you see it's **not** working is when you leave the input box and it turns red (default browser behaviour)

Is the regex pattern wrong? Or is it simply not possible to have URLs starting with www when the input type=url?

Here is my [regex101.com test](https://regex101.com/r/bF1bO9/2).

```
<p>
    <input required pattern="https?:\/\/.+|www.+" name="myURL" type="url" placeholder="Enter url" >
</p>    
<p>
    <input id="myComment" name="myComment" type="text" placeholder="not in use">
</p>
```

Comment: _"I've tried ... but it's not working"_ doesn't give us any idea what you expect this to do... It doesn't look like anything is going to happen until you try to validate the page/form.

Comment: The way you see it's not working, is when you leave the input box and it turns red (default browser behaviour)

Comment: `url` type requieres schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url` input type comes with it's own validation. If you want to accept input that is broader than what that type allows, then use the basic `text` input type and pair that with whatever validation pattern you prefer.

Comment: Ah. So the default validation will override my validation pattern?

Comment: Actually, `pattern` is [allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url) for `type="url"`. However, the way the pattern is processed looks different between the two input types.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern attribute specifies a regular expression that the  element's value is checked against on form submission.

In your case i think this regex will work:
`(hhttps?:\/\/)?(www\.)+.*`

You can play around with regex at: https://regexr.com/

You can learn more about `pattern attribute` at: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp